# Flutter Doctor crash

Tags: flutter, terminal, crash, flutter-doctor

I'm following the instructions to install flutter, it's my first install and I'm being careful not to miss a step. But...

Everything is going well until I try to run flutter doctor. I have updated the path and all is well.
I've edited the .bash_profile adding this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
```

echo $PATH and which flutter are both correct.
Please see the screenshot attached.

Running on macOS Sierra, version 10.12.6 // Flutter version: flutter_macos_2.0.1-stable

[Terminal: Flutter Doctor Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHL6A.png)

EDIT:
I've done what you suggested:

- My Mac is running 64-bits OK.
- I have installed brew OK
- `brew install dart` with some errors [image: see screenshot]
- refresh and run `flutter doctor -v`with crash
- 1)[image: screenshots 1]
- 2)[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Please could you post the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: `flutter doctor -v` output screenshot added (after brew install & brew install dart).

Answer (score 0):

First, verified if the your mac is 64-bits, [click here for know how](https://www.alesis.com/kb/article/1616#mac).

In Mac the Flutter run only in architecture 64-bits;

If the your mac is the 64-bits try install the dart using the [Brew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation);

After install brew, open the terminal and run the command:

```
brew install dart
```

Now run the flutter doctor;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a way around my issue.

As I cannot upgrade my Mac (for now), which I think was part of the problem, I tried to downgrade my Flutter version.
I installed 1.22.0-stable. Now flutter doctor runs OK-ish.

The only thing now is, having a mid-2010 MacOS 10.12.6 (Sierra), not being able to upgrade to (at least) Mojave, I cannot install Xcode 11, which is the minimum version allowed so I can compile on IOS.

Anyway, for now it seems to run fine: Android Studio - Flutter & Dart plugins - Android Simulator.

Although, working on a Mac and not being able to run/work on an IOS app is a bit frustrating, not gonna lie...